# Two or more data types in declaration of 'parameters' using mingw cross compiler under linux

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, mingw

I am trying to cross compile some code for windows using MinGw. The code is fairly simple:

Header:

```
    class DragLabel : public QLabel
    {

        Q_OBJECT

            public:
                DragLabel();
                void fn(QString path, int id, bool small);
    };
```

cpp:
        #include "draglabel.h"

```
    DragLabel::DragLabel()
    {
       /* Snip ... */
    };

    void DragLabel::fn(QString path, int id, bool small)
    {
        (void)d;
    };
```

The example function fails to compile givin me:

> > error: two or more data types in declaration of 'parameter'

for the declaration of fn(QString...).
[EDIT:] Sorry i forgot to mention that this error happens only if there is the bool variable declared, so the function without:

```
void fn(QString path, int id);
```

Workes just fine.

It compiles fine using qmake and make under debian linux.

Does anyone know what might happens here?
Thanks

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on the class.

Comment: ...And you don't need them at the end of method definition curly braces.

Comment: Sorry, i retyped that just know and forgot to add the semicolon. But the file contains the semicolon.

Comment: I know that i don't need them, but they are still allowed, no?

Comment: They're allowed as it's equivalent to a empty statement.  The error your are receiving is usually down to a semi-colon missing from a class or struct declaration - have you checked all of _your_ classes in other files?

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: @cmannett85 Yes I checked that before, I have only standart includes (Qt, stdlib / windows.h) and I do not use any struct at any time. I also checked whether bool has some other strange name under windows, so far no sucess. When i change everything to int it works, but this is not the nicest solution.

Comment: It seems, that somewhere declared type `small`

Comment: @cmannett85 it was probably downvoted because i was sloppy when posting my question. Sorry for that!

Comment: Or maybe it's not a type, but qualifier like `long` or `signed`. Maybe `small` is a extension of MinGW ?

Comment: @borisbn Yepp! You were right, it seems the small keyword is not allowed or interpreted as a type. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you found your answer, write an answer. Solutions do not go in questions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `small` is some extension keyword of MinGW (I couldn't find it in standard). According to

> When i change everything to int it works

`small` is some qualifier like `long` or `signed`, that extends `int` declaration.

Try to change variable name from `small` to anything else.